# Jquery extract text from html with special characters

Tags: jquery, html, special-characters

I want to extract the pure text from a piece of html. I know the common ways like .text(). However this does not seem to work. I receive a string that looks like this:

```
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 6pt; text-align: justify;"&gt;A concep&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o e projeto de qualquer produto requer do projetista a habilidade de examinar fatores que determinam o tipo (de produto), a informa&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o a ser exibida, o perfil de usu&amp;aacute;rio, o padr&amp;atilde;o de uso (do produto) e a intera&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o do usu&amp;aacute;rio com o produto. Perceba que esses fatores compreendem a base do que &amp;eacute; denominado &amp;ldquo;user experience&amp;rdquo;. Mas, o que &amp;eacute; &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt;? Trata-se da experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio quando interage com produtos ou servi&amp;ccedil;os. Aqui, produto pode ser qualquer coisa como, por exemplo, um fog&amp;atilde;o, uma ma&amp;ccedil;aneta de porta, um painel de autom&amp;oacute;vel, um iPod, um iPad ou software. Qualquer desses produtos ou at&amp;eacute; servi&amp;ccedil;os (como oferecidos em web sites), t&amp;ecirc;m a usabilidade como atributo determinante da qualidade percept&amp;iacute;vel aos usu&amp;aacute;rios. Tudo isso nos remete a uma caracter&amp;iacute;stica importante a qualquer produto ou servi&amp;ccedil;o: simplicidade. Nesse sentido, este artigo trata de &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt; (experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio) pode ser considerada para prover maior usabilidade a produtos na era da conectividade.&lt;/p&gt;
```

If I use the well known ways of extracting the text, it just leaves the html tags.

I want to keep the chars, represented by the special characters, e.g. `&amp;` but I want to strip the html tags, like e.g. `&lt;p class`=... Is there a clean solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Hanlets answer I found a solution that works. However, it still looks not really elegant to me and maybe someone knows a better way.

```
var myStr = '&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 6pt; text-align: justify;"&gt;A concep&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o e projeto de qualquer produto requer do projetista a habilidade de examinar fatores que determinam o tipo (de produto), a informa&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o a ser exibida, o perfil de usu&amp;aacute;rio, o padr&amp;atilde;o de uso (do produto) e a intera&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o do usu&amp;aacute;rio com o produto. Perceba que esses fatores compreendem a base do que &amp;eacute; denominado &amp;ldquo;user experience&amp;rdquo;. Mas, o que &amp;eacute; &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt;? Trata-se da experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio quando interage com produtos ou servi&amp;ccedil;os. Aqui, produto pode ser qualquer coisa como, por exemplo, um fog&amp;atilde;o, uma ma&amp;ccedil;aneta de porta, um painel de autom&amp;oacute;vel, um iPod, um iPad ou software. Qualquer desses produtos ou at&amp;eacute; servi&amp;ccedil;os (como oferecidos em web sites), t&amp;ecirc;m a usabilidade como atributo determinante da qualidade percept&amp;iacute;vel aos usu&amp;aacute;rios. Tudo isso nos remete a uma caracter&amp;iacute;stica importante a qualquer produto ou servi&amp;ccedil;o: simplicidade. Nesse sentido, este artigo trata de &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt; (experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio) pode ser considerada para prover maior usabilidade a produtos na era da conectividade.&lt;/p&gt;'

var d1= $("<div/>").html($("<div/>").html(myStr).text())
d2=d1.text()
console.log(d2);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpq24qv/3/

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
var myStr = '&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 6pt; text-align: justify;"&gt;A concep&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o e projeto de qualquer produto requer do projetista a habilidade de examinar fatores que determinam o tipo (de produto), a informa&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o a ser exibida, o perfil de usu&amp;aacute;rio, o padr&amp;atilde;o de uso (do produto) e a intera&amp;ccedil;&amp;atilde;o do usu&amp;aacute;rio com o produto. Perceba que esses fatores compreendem a base do que &amp;eacute; denominado &amp;ldquo;user experience&amp;rdquo;. Mas, o que &amp;eacute; &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt;? Trata-se da experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio quando interage com produtos ou servi&amp;ccedil;os. Aqui, produto pode ser qualquer coisa como, por exemplo, um fog&amp;atilde;o, uma ma&amp;ccedil;aneta de porta, um painel de autom&amp;oacute;vel, um iPod, um iPad ou software. Qualquer desses produtos ou at&amp;eacute; servi&amp;ccedil;os (como oferecidos em web sites), t&amp;ecirc;m a usabilidade como atributo determinante da qualidade percept&amp;iacute;vel aos usu&amp;aacute;rios. Tudo isso nos remete a uma caracter&amp;iacute;stica importante a qualquer produto ou servi&amp;ccedil;o: simplicidade. Nesse sentido, este artigo trata de &lt;em&gt;user experience&lt;/em&gt; (experi&amp;ecirc;ncia do usu&amp;aacute;rio) pode ser considerada para prover maior usabilidade a produtos na era da conectividade.&lt;/p&gt;'

var decoded = $("<div/>").html(myStr).text();
console.log(decoded);
```

Output would get rid of the HTML, but leave the entities.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpq24qv/

Comment: Hi Hanlet. Thank you for the idea. However, this produces just the opposite of what I need :). The html tags (<p...></p>) are still there and the other special characters are not shown.....<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 6pt; text-align: justify;">A concep&ccedil;&atilde;o e projeto de qualquer produto requer …….</p>

Comment: I edited your JSFiddle and now it produces what I need. But I am still unsure if this is really the best solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpq24qv/3/

Comment: @user2133375 I think that looks great!